# Dynamically added widget works only after route change

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using the flutter [Slidable](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_slidable) widget inside a `SliverList`, where the list elements are pulled from an array. I use `setState` to update the list.

The problem I am having is that after the list update, I can see all new elements correctly, but the slidable functionality doesn't work. However, after entering a new page with `push` and leaving with `pop`, the slidable functionality starts working.

Why is this happening?

```dart
return SliverList(
  delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
        (context, index) => Card(
      child: InkWell(
        child: Slidable(
          key: Key(_fileList[index].key),
          actionPane: SlidableDrawerActionPane(),
          child: Container(
            child: ListTile(
              onTap: () {
                ...
              },
              title: Text(_fileList[index].subtitle),
              subtitle: Text(_fileList[index].subtitle),
            ),
          ),
          secondaryActions: <Widget>[
            IconSlideAction(
                caption: 'Delete',
                color: Colors.red,
                icon: Icons.delete,
                onTap: () {
                  ...
                }
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
    childCount: _fileList.length,
  ),
);
```

Updating is done like this:

```dart
setState(() {
  _fileList = newFileList;
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, i accidentally disabled and then re-enabled the `SlidableController`.

Answer (score 0):

i think you may try not to test on hot reload 
just type in terminal : `flutter run`